# How to setup ODBC connection via command line for Teradata driver?

Tags: windows-10, odbc, teradata, dsn, command-line-tool

I am trying to setup a Teradata ODBC User DSN via below command line code.

```
%WINDIR%\System32\odbcconf.exe CONFIGDSN "Teradata" "DSN=Test|Description=Test|SERVER=ServerName|Trusted_Connection=Yes|Database=Controltub|UID=<LoginId>"
%WINDIR%\SysWOW64\odbcconf.exe CONFIGDSN "Teradata" "DSN=Test|Description=Test|SERVER=ServerName|Trusted_Connection=Tes|Database=Controltub|UID=<LoginId>"
```

This code works fine for "SQL Server" driver. However when I try to make changes accordingly for Teradata ODBC creation, it fails without any error.
I get blank in text fields for server name/IP field & user id in ODBC window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked for me with the Teradata 16.20 Driver on Windows 7:

```
%WINDIR%\System32\odbcconf.exe CONFIGDSN “Teradata Database ODBC Driver 16.20” “DSN=Test|Description=Test|DBCName={server}|DefaultDatabase=DBC|MechanismName=TD2|Username={user}”
```

Once you create the DSN, you can go into the Registry under Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ODBC\ODBC.INI{DSN Name} and try the other property (key) names to customize the DSN creation further. What I provide should get you a basic DSN to connect to Teradata.

Replace *TD2* with *LDAP* if your environment uses LDAP authentication.

Comment: Thanks @Rob. It worked for me when I changed driver from “Teradata Database ODBC Driver 16.20” to "Teradata" only.

Comment: any idea if we can mask the password in above command or ask user to input it - masked ?

Comment: If you do not store the password in the DSN, the user will be prompted to supply it. Alternatively, Teradata Wallet may be a solution that works in your environment.

Comment: Yes. But I was looking for something which wont prompt user for password. Instead it should prompt the one who is doing ODBC setup for the first time :). Anyway, I used a VB Script which prompt for password input via Internet explorer and this password then passed to a function which will execute above command. Why VB ? I can code more here to mask password :) thanks !